# How to get python graph output into html webpage directly

Tags: python, html, pandas, graph

I am using different libraries like pandas and numpy for generating a dataframe, which eventually generate a graph.

Now, I need to show this graph into a simple webpage which is in HTML.

**Note: I am also willing to take 2-3 input from user in HTML page then pass that data to my python file. Afterwards, python file generates a graph based on given data(from HTML page) and I need to pass this graph to an HTML page.**

```
df[[main_data]].plot()
```

Here, main_data is variable whose value is coming from HTML page. And I am doing python code in SPYDER. **And I am not using any Framework.**

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This depends somewhat on what you mean by showing the graph as html. I can see a couple ways, the first and simplest is to save the figure as a PNG and then supply the path to the file in the html:

Python code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

s = pd.Series([1, 2, 3])
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
s.plot.bar()
fig.savefig('my_plot.png')
```

HTML:

```
<img src='my_plot.png'/>
```

The second way would be to encode the figure as base64. This has the advantage of being portable, and the disadvantage of making very large unwieldy html files. I am not a web programmer, so there may be other caveats as well that I am not aware of.

python:

```
import io
import base64

def fig_to_base64(fig):
    img = io.BytesIO()
    fig.savefig(img, format='png',
                bbox_inches='tight')
    img.seek(0)

    return base64.b64encode(img.getvalue())

encoded = fig_to_base64(fig)
my_html = '<img src="data:image/png;base64, {}">'.format(encoded.decode('utf-8'))
```

`my_html` can be passed into you html file, or you can inject it with jinja2 or whatever you use. Here is SO post regarding viewing base64 in html https://stackoverflow.com/a/8499716/3639023 and encoding images as base64 [How to convert PIL Image.image object to base64 string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31826335/how-to-convert-pil-image-image-object-to-base64-string)

Comment: I would also give a shot to graph.js library. You can pass your data from python to HTML using the request library (or implementing a framework like Django or Flask)

Answer (score 7):

The best way to export matplotlib charts to the web browser is to Use mpld3 library. 
**Here is the example.**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import mpld3
from mpld3 import plugins
np.random.seed(9615)

# generate df
N = 100
df = pd.DataFrame((.1 * (np.random.random((N, 5)) - .5)).cumsum(0),
                  columns=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'],)

# plot line + confidence interval
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.grid(True, alpha=0.3)

for key, val in df.iteritems():
    l, = ax.plot(val.index, val.values, label=key)
    ax.fill_between(val.index,
                    val.values * .5, val.values * 1.5,
                    color=l.get_color(), alpha=.4)

# define interactive legend

handles, labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels() # return lines and labels
interactive_legend = plugins.InteractiveLegendPlugin(zip(handles,
                                                         ax.collections),
                                                     labels,
                                                     alpha_unsel=0.5,
                                                     alpha_over=1.5, 
                                                     start_visible=True)
plugins.connect(fig, interactive_legend)

ax.set_xlabel('x')
ax.set_ylabel('y')
ax.set_title('Interactive legend', size=20)

mpld3.show()
```

https://mpld3.github.io/quickstart.html

Answer (score 3):

You can also use `Plotly` for that. This provides more `interactive graphs`.
Also you can write the generated data in `HTML files, apply bootstrap styling`.

Check out [this tutorial on their website](https://plot.ly/python/v3/html-reports/).

Answer (score 1):

You may like to save the graph into specific location and write script to read the image file lets say `pic.png` into `HTML`. For taking input, you may create a `Tabular` structure of data and after each input, save the data to a file, lets say `file.csv` and read it in `Python` and keep adding values from input.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df.hist()
plt.savefig('path/to/pic.png')
```

Now create HTML code to read that image file and output it as you want. I hope this helps.