How can I display a matplotlibfinance graph on a html page using Flask?
I am currently doing a project for school, where we have to use Flask, online forms and CSVs to create a website. My website is based on finance and stocks, so I used the yfinance library to get data and plot it using matplotlib.
my code:
import yfinance as yf
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import datetime as dt
import mplfinance as mpf
import csv
from flask import Flask, render_template, request

with open('nasdaq.csv', 'r') as t:
    nasdaq_dict = list(csv.DictReader(t, delimiter=';'))
    stocks_list = [stock['company'] for stock in nasdaq_dict]

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
 return render_template('index.html', arr = [stocks_list])

@app.route('/resultat',methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def resultat():
  result = request.args
  stock = result['stock']
  date = result['full_date']
  index_stock = stocks_list.index(stock)
  ticker = [ticker['ticker'] for ticker in nasdaq_dict if ticker["company"] == stock]

  df = yf.download(ticker, period="max", actions=True)
  filename = stock + ".csv"
  df.to_csv(filename)

  file = filename
  data = pd.read_csv(file)
  data.Date = pd.to_datetime(data.Date)
  data = data.set_index('Date')
  graph = mpf.plot(data, type = 'candle', title = f'{stock}' + 'price', 
                    mav = 20, 
                    volume=True, 
                    tight_layout = True, 
                    style = 'yahoo')
  
  return render_template("resultat.html", stock = stock, full_date = date, ticker = ticker[0], graph = graph)

app.run(debug=True)

Everything works, apart from the graph (the code to make the graph itself works, I tested it separately, I just can't manage to send the graph over to "resultat_html", which would be the html page that someone would see after filling out a form.
Problem area:
df = yf.download(ticker, period="max", actions=True)
  filename = stock + ".csv"
  df.to_csv(filename)

  file = filename
  data = pd.read_csv(file)
  data.Date = pd.to_datetime(data.Date)
  data = data.set_index('Date')
  graph = mpf.plot(data, type = 'candle', title = f'{stock}' + 'price', 
                    mav = 20, 
                    volume=True, 
                    tight_layout = True, 
                    style = 'yahoo')
  
  return render_template("resultat.html", stock = stock, full_date = date, ticker = ticker[0], graph = graph)

When testing the graph separately, it worked perfectly, it opened up on my computer. When I tried adding it to my main code to add it to my website, it didn't work. I suspect you cannot just call the mpf.plot command "graph", but I'm honestly stuck.

I am not very familiar with flask, but I'm guessing there is a way to embed a figure.  If so, try using mplfinance's returnfig=True to gain access to the figure, and then attach the figure to the web page somehow.  Alternatively, you can always use kwarg savefig to save the figure as an image, and use html img tag to display the image.

See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49016797/1639359
