# The most space efficient way of storing images in memory in Python?

Tags: python, numpy, server, io, python-imaging-library

I'm currently working on a image server project in Python and I've been unable to find information on the most efficient way of storing the images in memory. I've tried using `sys.getsizeof` to try to get the size of the object in memory, but it doesn't return an accurate size for numpy arrays or PIL images. I've also thought about bypassing Python modules all together and storing the images in a `tmpfs` ramdisk and loading them back in when the images are requested. I'd appreciate any insights into the best practices for this problem.

Comment: `getsizeof` is pretty good at giving the size of `numpy` arrays, though you could also use `nbytes`.  It will also reflect the `np.save` size, because that essentially saves a copy of the array's data buffer.  There's no compression - just a straight save of the data.   But that may not be true for other image storing methods.

Comment: There are not nearly enough details here to be able to answer you. The most efficient way of storing images is obviously when they are compressed. But you give no indication of what type of images you are storing, nor for how many clients, nor why they can't be stored on disk?

Comment: You could try saving it as a base64 screen and convert it when read back in. [PIL image to b64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31826335/how-to-convert-pil-image-image-object-to-base64-string)